# testing with Vanity and with MySQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, vanity

I am trying to find a framework that allows me to do AB testing and I have found several: ABingo, Vanity and 7minutes AB. I am liking ABingo and Vanity and starting to like Vanity more  but the bad thing is that Vanity requires Redis (? is this true ?). I am just wondering if there is a workaround to use Vanity with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

No, Vanity can work with MySQL as well. To get it working in your development environment, just add the following to your config/environments/development.rb

```
Vanity.playground.establish_connection :development
```

Then, create a file called vanity.yml under config/ and add the following:

```
development:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: mysql
  host: localhost
  database: vanity
  username: my_username
  password: my_password
```